# How to pass Parse.com Cloud Code parameters correctly?

Tags: javascript, parameters, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am calling a cloud code function with Parse js

```
Parse.Cloud.run('enterproductwithid', 
     { 
         "token": token,
         "objId": objectIdOfCurrentProd,
         "username": currentUser1.username
     }
```

And my cloud code function is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("enterproductwithid", function(request, response) 
  {
     console.log(request.params);
  });
```

Only the token parameter is passed. Nothing else logs. Any thoughts so I can stop pulling my hair out?!

Thanks!!

Comment: The code is working fine for me. Have you checked that the variable you use in your request actually contain data and are not empty?

Answer (score 4):

Do not put the parameter keys in quotes. It is similar to a $.ajax POST function.

```
Parse.Cloud.run('enterproductwithid', 
      {
        token: token, 
        objId: objectIdOfCurrentProd, 
        username: currentUser1.username
      },{
      success: function(result) {
          //do neat stuff
      }, 
      error: function(e) {
         //error
      }
});
```